# Should individual products of a company have separate domains?

Tags: web, seo, dns

Let me explain the question with an example.

I have a company "abc" with url www.abc.com Now,the company has products: prod1, prod2 and prod3. Currently, I have maintained the websites for these products as:

www.abc.com/prod1/index.html,

www.abc.com/prod2/index.html and

www.abc.com/prod3/index.html respectively.

I have also purchased prod1.com, prod2.com and prod3.com which redirect to the urls mentioned above.

Should I maintain the websites of the products as www.prod1.com/index.html for prod1 and so on in order to help SEO?

Are there any benefits of maintaining separate domains for products of a company?

Please suggest which is the better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a moment, forget about SEO and think about your human users. They come to your corporate page and want to learn about your products. It looks very strange if every single product opens on a new domain in a new browser window. From that point of view, I would keep the products on the main site.

If you do so, make sure to establish a logic site structure, e.g. using:

```
/
/products
    /productA
        /Overview
        /Details
        /Special keyword page for this product
    /productB
        /Overview
        /Details
        /Special keyword page for this product
    /product...
        /...
```

Those pages are probably not changed very often as you are mainly presenting a highlevel view on what you offer.

From time-to-time you might want to run some campaigns. In that case, microsites come in handy. Here, it is often useful to put those on an extra domain with a domain name containing the most important keywords. Such microsites are often short lived, but highly optimized for the keywords you want to target. You link those microsites on the product page of your corporate site above and of course also use all other channels like social media to get some backlinks.

There's another reason to focus on one corporate site instead of several domains for each product. It saves you time and money, because you have to maintain only a single page. Don't underestimate what is needed to maintain different domains running different versions of a CMS with different templates, etc.

Of course everything said above makes only sense if your products are related. If your products are totally unrelated or one product's brand could be hurt if the customer is aware of your other products, it might be better to separate those products on different domains (think of selling car insurances but also offering some kind of money squeezing service).

Answer (score 1):

I would be interested to know the answer to this as well. This question is easy to answer "seo aside" but the only reason to do such a thing is for SEO purposes. From my experience, in the short term, it is much easier to rank high for an individual product domain if people are typing that keyword name into search. Google says they frown upon it, but time after time, exact match keyword domains show up on the first page of search results.